# Performing string comparison with carriage return in bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, sh

Why does the following code fail in bash? Note, I am trying to perform a more complex comparison such as "somestring\r"; this is just a simplified example.

I can confirm that the carriage return "ascii 13" is getting into the script. But I cannot compare against it with a regular string comparison.

The expected result is "1" for a positive match.

Command line:

```
echo -e "\r" | ./test.sh
```

Script:

```
ord() {
   printf '%d' "'$1"
}

read a
echo "1st char: $(ord ${a:0:1})"

left="${a:0:1}"

if [ "$left" = "\r" ]; then
   echo 1
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following would illustrate how you can determine if the string contains a carriage return:

```
read a
if [[ $a =~ $'\r' ]]; then
  echo 1;
fi
```

Executing it by saying:

```
echo -e "something\r" | bash foo
```

would return

```
1
```

---

EDIT: If you want to figure whether the last character of a string contains a carriage return, you could say:

```
if [[ ${a: -1} = $'\r' ]]; then
  echo 1;
fi
```

Comment: A good try but what I want is to perform an exact-match comparison against a substring.

Comment: Just replace `=~` with `=`. The `$'...'` syntax is not special to regular-expression matching; it's just a way of constructing a string in which certain escaped characters have special meaning.

Comment: @Zhro chepner has already mentioned in the comment.  However, see the edit above.

Comment: Thank you, chepner, that does appear to work. To confirm, if I want to include bash variable expansion as well, I'd have to construct it like this: `"test"$'\r'` to match against `test\r`, correct? I now recall the '$' syntax but I use it so rarely I'd forgotten!